# How to set a value of a child Form Group using Angular2 Model Driven Form?

Tags: angular

I am looking to change the value of a select box  once a button is clicked. I have written the entire form in Model Driven approach. The select box is inside a child Form Group.

```
 this.profileForm = this.fb.group({

    name: this.fb.control('',[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3) ]),
    website: this.fb.control('',[Validators.pattern('^(http|https|ftp)?(://)?(www|ftp)?.?[a-z0-9-]+(.|:)([a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$')]),
    contributor: this.fb.control('',[Validators.email]),
    dealershipLevel: this.fb.control('single',[ Validators.required ]),
    manufacturer: this.fb.control('',[ Validators.required ]),

    address : this.fb.group({
        addressline: this.fb.control('',[ Validators.required ]),
        city: this.fb.control('',[ Validators.required ]),
        state: this.fb.control('',[ Validators.required ]),
        zip: this.fb.control('',[ Validators.required ])

    })
})
```

I want to set the value of **state** select box once a button is clicked. it is possible to set the value of parent Form group using the code

`this.profileForm.controls.manufacturer.setValue('Tvm', { onlySelf: true });`

How to set value of a from control in the child form Group ?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.profileForm.get('address.state').setValue('Tvm', { onlySelf: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.profileForm.patchValue({address:{state:'Tvm'}}, { onlySelf: true });
```